# Files list file for package missing -- dpkg warning

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I want to install Open JDK or Oracle JDK to my machine but I got an error during installation. The error is:

```
Selecting previously unselected package oracle-java8-installer.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'unity-scope-gourmet' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'unity-scope-guayadeque' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'unity-scope-gmusicbrowser' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'unity-scope-manpages' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'unity-scope-gdrive' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'unity-scope-home' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I searched on Google and try to something for install/reinstall this packages. Finally i try to remove Unity. I faced this error for my every tries. I am using Xmonad. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One loop over the seven packages' names to recreate the list-file for each package.

But first run

```bsh
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

to remove unneeded DEBs in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. This is **necessary** that the following commands work properly.

```bsh
arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)"
for p in
  unity-scope-gourmet unity-scope-guayadeque unity-scope-gmusicbrowser
  unity-scope-manpages unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks unity-scope-gdrive
  unity-scope-home
do
    find /var/cache/apt/archives -type f -name "${p}_*_${arch}.deb" -exec dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile {} \; -quit | tar t | cut -f2- -d. | sed 's|^/$|/.|;s|/$||' | sudo tee "/var/lib/dpkg/info/$p.list" > /dev/null
done
sudo chmod -R a+r /var/lib/dpkg/info
```

---

Some tests later, the command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-scope-gourmet unity-scope-guayadeque unity-scope-gmusicbrowser unity-scope-manpages unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-home
```

should also help.

Comment: `dpkg-deb` shouldn't need `sudo`, the `find` command should probably be terminated after the first match. And instead of `dpkg-deb -c ... | awk ... | `, where you're processing `tar`'s verbose output, you could use `tar` to print only the paths: `dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile {} | tar t | ...`

Comment: Can you explain in detail one command to recreate? What if I do not want to `install` but to `remove` the package?

Comment: @Timo: If you want to remove the package you should still reinstall it to recreate its file list first and only then remove it, so that Apt knows which files to remove.

Answer (score -1):

I tried it A.B.'s approach but i faced same error with unity-scope-devhelp. Then, i deleted /var/lib/dpkg/unity-scope-devhelp.list

It Works :)

Comment: Why didn't you adapt A.B.'s method for `unity-scope-devhelp`?