# dpkg error: firefox-locale-en list missing

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

When I do anything with `apt` or `dpkg` I get this error:

```
dpkg: warning: file with the list of files from package 'firefox-locale-en' is missing;
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I already did:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get -m install
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install -m
sudo apt-get purge firefox
sudo apt-get install firefox
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And I still get the same problem!

This could be seen as a duplicate of:
[Files list file for package missing -- dpkg warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715558/files-list-file-for-package-missing-dpkg-warning),
But it is not. That has other packages so completely other solutions than mine.

Comment: So what if the linked question is about different packages? The solution is the same. Just replace the package name(s). In short: `sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall firefox-locale-en`