# ran the line sudo apt-get install google* now everything is wrong

Tags: apt, google-chrome, uninstall, android

I was trying to download google chrome and I got lazy and typed:

`sudo apt-get install google*`

It proceeded to download a lot of google android installers. When I realized what happened I closed the terminal to stop the processes.

Now I continuously get this error when updating, attempting to delete, attempting to download/install, basically anything involving apt:

```
files list file for package 'google-android-platform-21-installer' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I have looked up solutions for a few days now without a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Output of `dpkg -l | grep -i google`

```
ii  fonts-noto-color-emoji                     0~20180424-0ubuntu1                              all          color emoji font from Google  
ii  fonts-roboto-hinted                        2:0~20160106-2                            all          Google's signature family of fonts (hinted)  
ii  google-android-build-tools-17-installer    17.0.0                                    amd64        Google build tools 17 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)  
ii  google-android-build-tools-18-installer    18.1.1                                    amd64        Google build tools 18 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)  
ii  google-android-build-tools-19-installer    19.0.3                                  amd64        Google build tools 19 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)  
ii  google-android-build-tools-20-installer    20.0.0                                    amd64        Google build tools 20 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)  
ii  google-android-build-tools-21-installer    21.1.2                                    amd64        Google build tools 21 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)  
ii  google-android-build-tools-22-installer    22.0.1                                    amd64        Google build tools 22 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)  
ii  google-android-build-tools-23-installer    23.0.3                                    amd64        Google build tools 23 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)  
ii  google-android-build-tools-24-installer    24.0.2                                    amd64        Google build tools 24 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)  
ii  google-android-build-tools-installer:i386  23.0.3                                    i386         Google build tools for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)  
ii  google-android-m2repository-installer      41                                        all          Google Android support m2 repository  
ii  google-android-ndk-installer               13b                                       amd64        Google Android Native Development Kit (NDK) Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-10-installer       10+r02                                    all          Google's Android SDK Platform 10 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-11-installer       11+r02                                    all          Google's Android SDK Platform 11 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-12-installer       12+r03                                    all          Google's Android SDK Platform 12 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-13-installer       13+r01                                    all          Google's Android SDK Platform 13 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-14-installer       14+r04                                    all          Google's Android SDK Platform 14 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-15-installer       15+r05                                    all          Google's Android SDK Platform 15 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-16-installer       16+r05                                    all          Google's Android SDK Platform 16 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-17-installer       17+r03                                    all          Google's Android SDK Platform 17 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-18-installer       18+r03                                    all          Google's Android SDK Platform 18 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-19-installer       19+r04                                    all          Google's Android SDK Platform 19 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-2-installer        2+r1                                      all          Google's Android SDK Platform 2 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-20-installer       20+r02                                    all          Google's Android SDK Platform 20 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-21-installer       21+r02                                    all          Google's Android SDK Platform 21 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-22-installer       22+r02                                    all          Google's Android SDK Platform 22 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-23-installer       23+r03                                    all          Google's Android SDK Platform 23 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-24-installer       24+r02                                    all          Google's Android SDK Platform 24 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-3-installer        3+r04                                     all          Google's Android SDK Platform 3 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-4-installer        4+r03                                     all          Google's Android SDK Platform 4 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-5-installer        5+r01                                     all          Google's Android SDK Platform 5 Installer  
iF  google-android-platform-6-installer        6+r01                                     all          Google's Android SDK Platform 6 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-7-installer        7+r03                                     all          Google's Android SDK Platform 7 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-8-installer        8+r03                                     all          Google's Android SDK Platform 8 Installer  
ii  google-android-platform-9-installer        9+r02                                     all          Google's Android SDK Platform 9 Installer  
ii  google-android-sdk-docs-installer          24+r1                                     all          Android SDK Documentation from Google  
ii  google-cloud-print-connector               1.12-1                                    amd64        Google Cloud Print CUPS Connector  
ii  google-compute-engine-oslogin              20180510+dfsg1-0ubuntu4~18.04.1           amd64        Google Compute Engine OS Login  
ii  google-mock:amd64                          1.8.0-6                                   amd64        Google's framework for writing and using C++ mock classes  
ii  google-perftools                           2.5-2.2ubuntu3                            all          command line utilities to analyze the performance of C++ programs  
ii  googleearth-package                        1.2.2                                     all          utility to automatically build a Debian package of Google Earth  
ii  googlefontdirectory-tools                  20120309.1-1.1                            all          various tools for generating, analysing and manipulating font   files  
ii  googler                                    3.5-1                                     all          Power tool to Google (Web & News) and Google Site Search from the   terminal  
ii  googletest:amd64                           1.8.0-6                                   amd64        Google's C++ test framework  
ii  libgoogle-perftools4                       2.5-2.2ubuntu3                            amd64        libraries for CPU and heap analysis, plus an efficient thread-  caching malloc  
ii  libguava-java                              19.0-1                                    all          Suite of Google common libraries for Java  
ii  libsisu-guice-java                         4.2.0-1                                   all          Patched build of Google Guice for Sisu-IoC  
ii  translate-shell                            0.9.6.6-1                                    all          Google Translate to serve as a command line tool
```

Comment: Please run `dpkg -l | grep -i google` and add the output of this command to your question.

Comment: I think you need to delete every package using `sudo apt autoremove <package name>`. Tip: You can remove these android-installer using `sudo apt autoremove google-android-platform*` in one go

Comment: @kulfy I have tried that. It just returns errors saying that it cannot find any of those packages using (glob, regex) and the standard way.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/715656/816190) might help. Not exactly same question but somewhat similar.

Comment: Did you search for `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)`? There are quite a few search results for that. Also, it's good practice to post the entire output of commands and the entire exact command, if it isn't too long, here rather than snippets. You can do do by copy/pasting from the terminal and using the site's formatting tools: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help.

Comment: I did try that, I have looked it up and tried many different methods all to no prevail. And thank you for that link.