# Trying to get apt-upgrade working again on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

My Ubuntu Server runs in a virtual machine. Unfortunately the server it runs on was restarted recently, causing corruption which required a full disk fsck to get it booting again.

When I tried to update and upgrade packages, I got error messages which I include below. apt update works as usual but the apt upgrade command causes an error. When I run dpkg -- configure -a, I get other error messages. I have tried removing and purging the packages mentioned but nothing seems to work.

I have tried the solution suggested but get the following error message:

[image]

Any ideas? This screen has the original errors...

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix dpkg error \[2\]?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603295/how-to-fix-dpkg-error-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Files list file for package missing -- dpkg warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715558/files-list-file-for-package-missing-dpkg-warning)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the .list files were corrupt.

I managed to solve this using the advice on https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/apt-get-dpkg-error-files-list-file-missing-final-newline-271118/

I deleted the list files, purged and reinstalled the packages and it all eventually started updating/upgrading without error.