# Getting an error while running "sudo apt-get upgrade"

Tags: upgrade, dpkg

```
setting xserver-xorg-legacy/xwrapper/allowed_users from configuration file
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsamplerate0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsane-hpaio:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libqt5webkit5:amd64' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

How to fix the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Files list file for package missing — dpkg warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715558/files-list-file-for-package-missing-dpkg-warning)?

Comment: Remove and uninstall the whole file. sudo apt-get remove libsamplerate0:amd64 libsane-hpaio:amd64 libqt5webkit5:amd64

Comment: Then, you should reinstall the packages with sudo apt-get installibsamplerate0:amd64 libsane-hpaio:amd64 libqt5webkit5:amd64

Comment: This stack may help: https://serverfault.com/questions/430682/dpkg-warning-files-list-file-for-package-x-missing?newreg=f6f1bba156894045b915188694c62947

Comment: yes i tried sudo apt-get autoremove and sudo apt-get autoclean